# Ubuntu on my new Chromebook sets the time 20+ years in future

Tags: mysql, chromebook, date

After 3-4 days since LAMP stack installation on the Chrome book, the time went to future. I don't really mind it, but MySQL community server doesn't work with years higher than 2038. Sync over internet wouldn't work for me, because my app was designed to run on localhost. Do you know what could be the cause of the problem and what the solution could be for that? There is no dual boot on the computer.

**EDIT:** The issue got fixed after several attempts of `date -s "current date"` and reboot. I don't know if the error will come back again since I'm not sure how I fixed it. [On boot Ubuntu showed me this when it got fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXrAH.jpg). If you have an idea on what the root of the problem is, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Possible cause: a bug in using `hwclock` or `ntp` bug getting nonsense data. I remember 2043 as the year it got set to. Let's see how good my memory is. Guessing .. 2013, 2014 when I saw this.

Comment: 2012 HA!. https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1058225  2011 http://voyage-linux.34677.n3.nabble.com/ntp-does-not-start-on-reboot-hwclock-does-not-have-usable-clock-interface-td3342063.html